# why when I turn off cast shadow, the light can through the mesh?

Tags: light

in first image, just simple scene, but in second image when I turn off cast shadow, the light going through to bottom room.
Blender 2.78a - Cycles
[image: use cast shadow]

[image: cast shadow is off]

Comment: You turn of `Cast Shadow` and the light doesn't cast a shadow . . . what did you expect to happen . . ?

Comment: the light is exist in bottom room, I just want to add light in upper room, but when I disable cast shadow, the bottom room get enlightened

Comment: @novice rofl, brutal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The `Cast Shadow` option enables or disables shadows for a specific lamp in the scene. When you disable shadows, all faces act as if they have direct light on them.

Comment: so in first image the reason the bottom room is dark because the shadow from middle floor? and when I disable the cast shadow the bottom room is get enlightened? thanks, I understand now, thanks for @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ too :D


-by the way, my goal in this scene is having light in upper room, and not have any light in bottom, in upper room i use multiple light so object in that room have multiple shadow too, thats why i want to disable shadow in some light.

Comment: disabling cast shadows for one lamp will make it not cast shadows on any objects